# Cannot find Node in document using querySelector

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, puppeteer

---

## The Elusive NodeList

---

> I have been stuck on this for *3 weeks now*. I have tried literally
>   hundreds of attempts to get this to work. I simply cannot figure out
>   what is going wrong. I've run out of possible solutions to try.

That being said...

**Quick Summary Of Application**

I recently accepted a side job to develop an app that will notify the client whenever a new Jeep Wrangler is posted to Facebook Marketplace. It sounded fairly straight-forward, and I accepted the job. I estimated completion in three days max. That was last month. Below is a flowchart of how the application will work:

[image: Facebook Marketplace Scraper Flowchart]

**Technology**

After quite a bit of research, I decided to go with [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to develop the app.

**Step 1: The Scrape**

I had to familiarize myself with the page holding the information needed. This is the search results page:

https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/tampa/search/?query=jeep%20wrangler&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false

As you will see, the results are listed in a grid format. So I need to grab the container holding the list of items...

[image: Facebook Search Results Container]

```
<!-- This is the DIV that is the container nodelist -->
<div class="bq4bzpyk j83agx80 btwxx1t3 lhclo0ds jifvfom9 muag1w35 dlv3wnog enqfppq2 rl04r1d5">
```

I found this by inspecting the console:

[image: Inspecting]

I used the same method to find the elements that hold **title**, **price**, and the **image**. That information is a child node of the containing element above.

[image: Sample Listing]

**Step 2: The Code**

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to get a minimal working version that will scrape looking for an "iPhone X" as the search query. It works great! But when I tried to adapt this code, by simply changing the search keyword to "Jeep Wrangler", it failed. Here is a Gist of the working code:

https://gist.github.com/johnsdeveloper/1a7d02554dbfd682ee274b2ef0696f00

**My Code**

Taking that working code, I came up with my source code below. It is not working. I get this error every time:

> **(node:4928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined    at removeDupes (C:\wamp64\www\puppeteer\index.js:56:32)
>       at initScraper (C:\wamp64\www\puppeteer\index.js:86:27)
>   (node:4928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.**

It appears the new listing results are coming back empty, meaning the "scrape" did not work.

Here is my complete code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
var fileName = "./public/data/newjeeps.json";
var changed = false;
var browser;

const getItems = async searchTerm => {
    //{headless: false, defaultViewport: null} --> put this in launch() method below as parameter for developtment purposes --> opens up browser window
    //const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, defaultViewport: null});

     browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ["--no-sandbox"]

    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(`https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/tampa/search/?query=jeep%20wrangler&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false`);
    await autoScroll(page);

    const itemList = await page.waitForSelector('#mount_0_0 > div > div > div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb > div > div > div.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.d6urw2fd.dp1hu0rb.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb > div > div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.d2edcug0.rj1gh0hx.buofh1pr.g5gj957u.hpfvmrgz.dp1hu0rb > div')
    .then(() => page.evaluate(() => {
        const itemArray = [];
        const itemNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('#mount_0_0 > div > div > div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb > div > div > div.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.d6urw2fd.dp1hu0rb.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb > div > div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.d2edcug0.rj1gh0hx.buofh1pr.g5gj957u.hpfvmrgz.dp1hu0rb > div > div > div > div > div > div > span > div > a');

        itemNodeList.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item);
        });
        return itemArray;
    }))
    .catch(() => console.log("Selector error."));

    return itemList;

}

/**
 * Remove any duplicates from JSON files
 *
 * @param {*} existingResults
 * @param {*} newResults
 * @returns array Returns new array of unique listings
 */
const removeDupes = async function (existingResults, newResults) {

  var existingTitle;
  var newTitle;
var newResults;

  /* Loop through EXISTING (marketplacebot.json) */
  for (var i = 0; i < existingResults.length; i++) {
    /* Existing Title & Price TODO*/
    existingTitle = existingResults[i].itemTitle;
    /* Loop through NEW data */
    for (y = 0; y < newResults.length; y++) {
      /* New Title */
      newTitle = newResults[y].itemTitle;
      /* Do we have a match? */
      if (existingTitle == newTitle) {

console.log("match");
        // Remove from new results
        newResults.splice(y, 1);

        // Change detected?
        changed = true;

      }
    }
  }

  return newResults;
}

const initScraper = async() => {

    // Get currently listed items on Marketplace
    const items = await getItems('Jeep Wrangler');
    //items.sort(function(a, b){return a.itemPrice - b.itemPrice});

    // Get existing JSON from file
    const existing = await jsonfile.readFile(fileName);

    // Compare the two, save only the differences
    const results = await removeDupes(existing,items);
    //console.log(results);

   // Now save the differences back to the JSON files, the
   // web page will pick up and display.
   var success = await jsonfile.writeFile(fileName, results);

    // If there were any differences, notify me
    if(changed == true){
      const page2 = await browser.newPage();
      await page2.goto('http://sendmail.com/mail.php');
    }

}

initScraper();





 // This takes care of the auto scrolling problem
 async function autoScroll(page) {
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      var totalHeight = 0;
      var distance = 100;
      var timer = setInterval(() => {
        var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        window.scrollBy(0, distance);
        totalHeight += distance;

        if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight || scrollHeight>7000) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          resolve();
        }
      }, 100);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This approach looks very flakey. A selector like `'div > div > span > div > a > div > div > div > span > div > span > div[class="l9j0dhe7 stjgntxs ni8dbmo4"'` is extremely sensitive to changes in layout and unless you understand the class structure, extremely sensitive to changes in class values. E.g. a div is not allowed as a child of a span, so `div > span > div` is problematic. Probably a selector like `'.l9j0dhe7', '.stjgntxs',  '.ni8dbmo4'` would work better, but again without knowing what the class values mean or how they might change, you're just stumbling in the dark.

Comment: Other then basic css selectors, this is new to me, however, your comment makes perfect sense. I have tried your suggestion, but still no luck. Hopefully I can get this working.

Comment: I did some Googling and it seems the only folks having decent success were using Python driving Selenium (basically, "Headless Chrome") and had to frequently tweak the Xpath mapping to get it to work with FB's latest changes. Due to heavy use of JS, normal scraper libs has little success against FB Marketplace.

Comment: @KaseyChang—indeed. I expect that the layout and classes may change based on the detected device, ongoing development, developer whim, minifier being used, etc.

Comment: Ok I made SOME progress. I am able to get a NodeList of an anchor tab ( see my gist here: https://gist.github.com/johnsdeveloper/4584af4f09e1faaf2b3072e989e51ab4 )  -- now within this  <  a  >  tag is all the info I need. I just have to figure out how to parse this string. Would this method work? If I can get the title, img, and price out of that string, I am in great shape! Any ideas on how to get my info out of here?

Comment: Those Python/Selenium scripts don't have anything over Puppeteer FTR.

Answer (score 0):

Those classes are dynamic. You want to go by the other attributes or text on the page.

For example, get those `a` elements with: `a[href*="/item/"]`